# Add a new column 'Score' to the DataFrame with values based on existing categorical column Medal

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say: there is a data frame:

```
country       Edition     sports       Athletes           Medal  score
Germany          1990    Aquatics  HAJOS, Alfred          gold     3
Germany          1990    Aquatics  HIRSCHMANN, Otto       silver   2
Germany          1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios      silver   2
US               2008    Athletics MALOKINIS, Ioannis     gold     3
US               2008    Athletics HAJOS, Alfred          silver   2
US               2009    Athletics CHASAPIS, Spiridon     gold     3
France           2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold     3
France           2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold     3
France           2010    golf      HAJOS, Alfred          Bronze   1
France           2011    golf      ANDREOU, Joannis       silver   2
Spain            2011    golf      BURKE, Thomas          gold     3
```

bronze =1 ,silver =2 ,gold =3.

can anyone tell me how to assign these values to new column `'score'`? after adding new column `df['score']`?

Comment: `df['score']=df['Medal'].map({'Bronze':1,'silver':2,'gold':3})`?

Comment: Do these values ​​follow a logic based on the other columns of the dataframe? could you explain it?

Comment: No, it just follows the logic of Medal column.

Comment: Many ways to handle. e.g. `df["score"]=df["medal"].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=="Bronze" else (2 if x=="silver" else 3))`

Comment: So these values ​​are not counted for countries or athletes or sports?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with:

```
scores = {'gold':3,'silver':2,'bronze':1}                                                                                                                                           

df['scores'] = df['Medal'].map(scores)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html).

```
df['score']=df['Medal'].replace({'Bronze':1,'silver':2,'gold':3})
```

or as I suggested above: [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
df['score']=df['Medal'].map({'Bronze':1,'silver':2,'gold':3})
```